# How to test UIImageView elements in iOS XCTest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to test my UIs using XCTest UI testing, and having troubles of testing UIImageViewsI have in my app (hit tests, presence etc).

In the list of the XCUIElementType there is no such type, and when I look at the children of the superview my UIImageViews are not listed there for some reason eventhough I can see them on screen and in the UI inspector in the Xcode.

Has anyone had this kind of problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assert the presence of an image by its accessibility label.

**Production Code**

```
let image = UIImage(named: "profile")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.accessibilityIdentifier = "Your profile image"
```

**UI Test Code**

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
XCTAssert(app.images["Your profile image"].exists)
```

Comment: what if the imageView is a subview of the dynamic cell prototype ?

Comment: oh actually, I see how I can test for existence! Cool, what about tapping on it? I have the gesture recognizer attached to  the imageView?

Comment: figured XCUIElement* image = self.app.images[@"addToGroupButton1"];
    [image tap]; thank you!

Comment: How to check for multiple image updates(one after another) in a single UIImageView?

Comment: @Joe Masilotti Do you know how to check whether the image itself, instead of the imageView, does exist? thx.

Comment: Swift 4.     XCTAssert(app.images["Your profile image"].exists)