# XCUITest - is it possible to test the app icon?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcuitest

My apologies–I'm sure this question as been asked before but I am not able to find anything on this so I figured asking would be better.

My application allows the user to change the home screen icon. I want to test the icon when the user goes back to the home screen. Is there a way to do this in XCUItests?

Comment: I don't think it's possible right now. You may do it with a unit test.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568205/how-to-test-if-a-uiimageview-contains-an-image-with-a-specific-name-using-xcuite/56595165#56595165